# How to find the target date when specified weekday is given

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a situation where user define the weekday for delivery and its transit day.
When the estimate to arrival(ETA) date is given, I need to calculate the estimate to delivery (ETD) date base on the transit day.

Example:

```
ETA is 17/Jul/2013, Transit Day: 10 Days, Delivery Day: Tue / Fri
```

By using `AddDays(-10)`, the ETD would be `8/Jul/2013 (Mon)`. Due to delivery day is not drop on `Tue` or `Fri`, system need to look backward the calendar.

As result, system must take the `5/Jul (Fri)` as `ETD` date.

What is the best practice to archive this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public DateTime GetLastPosibleDate(DateTime datetime, List<DayOfWeek> days)
{
    DateTime dt = datetime;
    if (!days.Any(d=> d==dt.DayOfWeek))
    {
        dt=  GetLastPosibleDate(datetime.AddDays(-1), days);
    }
    return dt;
}

public DateTime EstimatedDiliveryDate(DateTime arrival, int transitDays, List<DayOfWeek> deliveryDays)
{
    return GetLastPosibleDate(arrival.AddDays(-transitDays), deliveryDays);
}
```

usage :

```
var arrival = new DateTime(2013,07,17);
var deliveryDays = new List<DayOfWeek>(){DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Friday};
var result = EstimatedDiliveryDate(arrival, 10, deliveryDays);
```

Comment: Your sample coding served exactly what I am looking! Thanks you so much, @Damith.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to iterate between days until you find the next delivery day according to your user's preference. You can see an example of this here: [Get Next Nth Fridays Date From Todays Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981106/c-sharp-get-next-nth-fridays-date-from-todays-date)